How to pass value from IN clause to subquery in Oracle PLSQL
I have a scenario where I need to pass the value from the IN clause to the subquery which returns a value for a particular column using Oracle PLSQL.
Suppose my main query is as below :
SELECT column1, column2, columnn3
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.colName= t2.colName
JOIN table3 t3 on t2.colName = t3.colName
WHERE column1 IN (12345, 67900, 23456...)

Now suppose the value for column2 in the main query is derived using another subquery which needs the column1 value which is present in IN clause. Example, the subquery needs value 12345 passed to it to calculate column2 value while it is getting the data when column1 = 12345. Similarly the subquery needs the value 67900 while it is getting data when column1 = 67900 and so on.
How can I pass the current iteration value of column1 to the subquery which calculates the value for column2?
I am not an expert with Oracle PLSQL concepts. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

It's quite hard to understand what you mean - but it seems like you just need to refer to column1 directly in the subquery? It doesn't really matter than it happens to be from the in clause. But you probably want to prefix all the column references with the table aliases (e.g. t1.column1, if that's where it comes from). And you might want another join rather than a subquery column expression, but that depends on your data of course.

@AlexPoole The subquery is quite complex where it has 3 queries in it to derive single column2 which will be a normal flag Y or N. Also, SQL does not allow to refer the main query column inside the subquery which can be up to 2 level deep. Basically I just want the subquery to be run for every value from IN clause.

You probably need to reorganise the subquery then, maybe using CTEs. Or if you don't mind repeating the in clause values, have that list in the subquery too, and make it an inline view you join to. (And if you do want to avoid the repetition you can use another CTE maybe.)  It would easier to understand and produce a sensible answer for if there was a more concrete example in the question - not your full real query but something representative.

Don't use the IN clause for passing in multiple keys. Either use a collection and read it like a table, or work row-by-row, one key at a time.

Tip. The value of column1 is not "present in the IN clause". It's present in some field of some table. Don't worry about the IN, which is just a filter solved BEFORE processing the SELECT clause. Please, see my answer below.

You can try the below, Also don't forget to put comma before and after the in clause string
SELECT column1, column2, columnn3
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.colName= t2.colName
JOIN table3 t3 on t2.colName = t3.colName
WHERE instr(',12345,67900,23456,', ','||cast(column1 as varchar(255))||',') > 0
order by instr(',12345,67900,23456,', ','||cast(column1 as varchar(255))||',')


I think you just need a correlated subquery. You can place it into the main SELECT (probably not the best performant choice, but it's clear and it works). I'll assume column1is part of table1. I'll also asume there's JUST ONE record in other_table that satisfies the condition. (If there is more than one, you'll need to aggregate them inside the subquery.) The other tables and the filtering conditions are not relevant to your problem (apparently).
SELECT t1.column1, (SELECT column2 FROM other_table WHERE id = t1.column1)
FROM table1 t1
  -- These joins are not related to your actual problem
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.colName = t2.colName
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.colName = t3.colName
-- The filtering conditions are not related to your actual problem
WHERE t1.column1 IN (12345, 67900, 23456...)

I usually prefer to join the subquery directly into the main query. This variant SEEMS to imply more work for the database, but that depends on several things (actual indexes, actual cardinality, etc). If you don't know about these things, don't worry and trust the optimizer.
SELECT t1.column1
FROM table1 t1
  -- These joins are not related to your actual problem
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.colName = t2.colName
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.colName = t3.colName
  -- These is relevant
  JOIN (SELECT id, column2 FROM other_table) other ON other.id = t1.column1
-- The filtering conditions are not related to your actual problem
WHERE t1.column1 IN (12345, 67900, 23456...)

Please be aware that the first variant will report an error if the subquery returns more than one record (per each id, etc) but the second one will silently duplicate information. When I use this second variant, I almost always pre-aggregate inside the subquery, just in case. If you're in doubt, just go with the first one.
Note: I didn't tested. The code may contain some minor syntax error.

An additional note: if you have a lot of values inside the IN clause (or if you need to dynamically construct that list of values), you need another (maybe complementary) solution. Let us know if that's the case.
